# VB.net SerialPort multithread

Tags: multithreading

I have made a program the receives an xml file via LAN (Net.Socket) and need to send a part of this XML data to a serial port (also to some labels)

When sending to the labels all goes well, because I'm using the following code (cross thread):

```
 Delegate Sub SetlblScoreLine1TextInvoker(ByVal TextToDisplay1 As String)

Public Sub SetlblScoreLine1Text(ByVal TextToDisplay1 As String)
    If lblScoreLine1.InvokeRequired Then
        lblScoreLine1.Invoke(New SetlblScoreLine1TextInvoker(AddressOf SetlblScoreLine1Text), New Object() {TextToDisplay1})
    Else
        lblScoreLine1.Text = TextToDisplay1
    End If
End Sub
```

I wanted to use this also for the serial port, but serialport1.invokerequired is not a member of systems.IO.ports.serialports.
This because not always the serial data is send correctly (cross thread??)

Any idea how I can solve this?

I'm not familiar with cross threads

Comment: That snippet has absolutely nothing to do with your problem.  Nobody can possible guess what "not always the serial data is send correctly" could possible mean.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I send data to the serial port, hope this helps:

```
                If SerialPort1.IsOpen = True Then
                SerialPort1.Write("2" & strLine2 & vbLf & vbCr _
                                  & "3" & strLine3 & vbLf & vbCr _
                                  & "4" & strLine4 & vbLf & vbCr)
                SerialPort1.Write("Cxx234xdx" & vbCrLf & vbCr)
            End If
```

If you need more information, please let me know